# Strange behaviour delete keyword phantomjs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner

### Context

I have a piece of code that runs through `karma` with `jasmine` and `phantomjs` as a browser, and my problem is that I can't figure out why the `delete` keyword does not do its job. I looked on phantomjs github to find a hint or a clear documentation about keywords support, in vain.

**UPDATE**

### It actually seems it does not work on chrome either now...

here is the output of the expectation

> ShopDataServiceTest should not have an instance method remove FAILED
>   Expected { getModelName : Function } not to have method 'remove'.

### Here is my tested code:

```
// CRUDService basically returns a new class
// with a prototype containing a method remove

ShopDataService = CRUDService.build(modelName);
delete ShopDataService.prototype.remove;
```

### Here the code that is executed by karma

```
expect(ShopDataService.prototype).not.toHaveMethod('remove');
```

### Important note

This code is running under karma and does not work in that case, ***<s>but it works when running on chrome</s>***, am I missing something here ?

---

**EDIT** I did not mention it before, the expression `typeof ShopDataService.prototype.remove` returns `'function'`, as [ppoliani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/512783/ppoliani) pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's the awkward moment when you realize you **prototyped** wrong !

### Why I was wrong

ShopDataService simply **does not** have its own property remove, since it is inherited from CRUD which has itself a method remove in its prototype.

**I had this**

```
var CRUD = function CRUD(modelName) {
        this.getModelName = function () {
            return modelName;
        };
    };

    CRUD.prototype = {
        save: function () {
            // ABSTRACT
        },
        /**
         * Deletes instance from id property
         * @return http promise
         */
        remove: function () {
            // call api
        }
    };
```

**And now it works with this**

```
var CRUD = function CRUD(modelName) {
        this.getModelName = function () {
            return modelName;
        };

        this.save = function () {};
        this.remove = function () {};
    };
```

As a side effect, I should not hit the CRUD prototype to define the remove method, but instead define it on the newly created prototype extending CRUD.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your code in 'strict mode'; it might not allow you to use the delete operator to full extent.

Comment: Well I get your point, I have strict mode enabled indeed. But the thing is I did not use any descriptor to  partially or fully freeze my prototype. That may also explain why disabling strict mode did not solve my problem...

Comment: When you say it doesn't work in Karma, you mean the assertion is false?

Comment: Yes, the assertion is false, no problem with the code itself.

Comment: can you check if the delete removes the method, indeed; Try something like this var deleted = typeof ShopDataService.prototype.remove !== 'function';

Comment: I tried earlier and it turns out it is still a function

Comment: Can you try to see if the object is sealed: Object.isSealed(ShopDataService.prototype)

Comment: Nope, I did not seal it, it returns `false`

Comment: Well I have a major update here, it seems it does not work on chrome either now.

Comment: I'll try to setup one, sure

Comment: While making the jsfiddle I realized that I was wrong all the way, I answered my own question